# Retain javascript data while Forward and Backward browser button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have following dropdown which calls javascript `showTable` method.

```
<select name="any_name" id="any_id" onChange="showTable()">
```

I have following `showTable` method which calls a php method via post to populate data in my `showData` div.

```
function showTable()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: {"Id" : myId},
        success: function (data) 
        {
            document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML= data;
        }
        });
    }
```

It works fine. Now the problem arises when I hit FORWARD and then BACKWARD browser button. On hitting BACKWARD button, I get my previous page but my `showData` div is empty. How can I retain data in this div which I got from my PHP script? I think I have made it clear what I want to ask.

Comment: Look for local storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and manage to save and retreive values between your back/forward behavior.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - Thanks for your comment. Local Storage has resolved my problem :)

Comment: You did it fast! Bravo!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - :) I wish I could upvote your comment, but I don't have that much reputation :(

Comment: Well, if you're that happy... I can use my comment for an answer... Wich you could accept. It will then mark your question as answered and prevent other to spend time trying... ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for local storage [w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and manage to save and retreive values between your back/forward behavior.

;)